# Android N : NDK Apps Linking to Platform Libraries

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-7.0-nougat

I know this is a daft question but I need a help, as mentioned in the Android N changes documentation regarding [NDK Apps Linking](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#ndk), they say I have to check if my application is accessing any android private library. the question is that if I have an application how to detect if this application or any of it's dependencies is accessing a private library ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `ndk-build`, we'll emit a warning if you link things that aren't explicitly allowed: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/17f4d9e8ec1d48db9035ca3103254a39efae3899/build/core/build-binary.mk#84

This warning can be circumvented by `dlopen`ing a non-NDK library, or by building your own stub to link against. If you run on Android N or newer, your app will not load if you've worked around this.

For other build systems, just make sure you're only linking things that are in your app (shipped in your APK) or are in the `system_libs` list (note that new libraries may be added to this in each release to support new APIs): https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/build/core/build-binary.mk#61

Comment: If I have an application which iIdidn't write it's code and I don't if these application is linking to any private library or not? How can I check it?

Comment: `readelf -d $THELIBRARY` will tell you what libraries it's linking to.

Comment: And how to know `THELIBRARY` that the application depends on it ? how to detect it ? I didn't write the application code so i don't know anything about what inside the cave but i need to check if the application or on of it's dependencies are linking to a private library ? how to check that ?

Comment: `find $OUT_DIR -name '*.so'`

Comment: What is the `OUT_DIR` ?

Comment: Whatever directory you're building the project to.

Comment: you the the project build directory ? Or the project parent directory ?

Answer (score 0):

use readelf -aD *libfile |grep "NEEDED" like mention above and or use patchelf to see the required libs and rpath, it's more useful imho.

Often times I get around android N private lib restrictions by using LDFLAGS to act as LDLIBS, or just statically link in the libs you depend on. I statically compile libc and often just pass -lc in LDFLAGS to generate static binaries.

I tend to get tired of the restrictions and just resort to making my own version of dependencies and adding them in

see here

https://github.com/Surge1223/interfacer/blob/n-rootless/jni/Android.mk

It's almost impossible for aosp devs to use jni libs without requiring root access.

I circumvented that in the link above

I need libbinder for IPC binder and for some reason libnativehelper is required but using the system version denies me access

Very annoying